# Excel help: How to fill a cell with data from a table dependent on multiple variables

Tags: excel, lookup, lookup-tables

I have a report sheet I have made on excel that has age, gender and skinfold measurements (in mm) and two tables displaying body fat percentages depending on skinfold measurement, age and gender.

I would like a cell to report the percentage of bodyfat depending on other cells (age, gender, skinfold)

So far I have the following equation:

```
=IF(AND(E8="MALE",B8<=19),LOOKUP(B18,Table2[17-19]))
```

With `B18 = 9.2`

The (male) table being looked up has skinfold in mm in the left column, and age ranges across the top (17-19, 20-29, 30-39, 40-49, 50+). At the moment the formula finds the closest value (10) in the age column 17-19, however I want the formula to find skinfold first then depending on what age range turn out the corresponding percentage.

The cell highlighted has the current formula in.

[image: Print Screen of Report]

Comment: if the given thickness is 9.2 , you'll refer to thickness 10 values. .. if the given thickness is 11.0 , will you refer to the 'thickness 10 ' or 'thickness 12'  values ?

Comment: Yes, precisely, the given values will only be estimates or presented using "<". e.g. age 17-19, thickness 10 = <0.41%; age 20-29 thickness 12 = <2.1% etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(B18<10,MOD(B18,2)<>0)," < ","") & INDEX(IF(E8="FEMALE",L5:P20,T5:X20),MATCH(INT(B18/2+0.95)*2,K5:K20,0),IF(AND(B8>=17,B8<=19),1,IF(AND(B8>=20,B8<=29),2,IF(AND(B8>=30,B8<=39),3,IF(AND(B8>=40,B8<=49),4,IF(B8>=50,5))))))
```

This seems to do it. In an overview.. :

1. If "FEMALE" look in `L5:P20` else `T5:X20` .
2. Match the age. (select row) if 9.2 convert to 10, 10.1 -> 12, 11.0 -> 12 by using `INT(B18/2+0.95)*2`
3. Lastly using the range defined, identify in which column @ `L5:P20` or `T5:X20` data range should the value be taken from.
4. display " < " if there is no exact match using `IF(OR(B18<10,MOD(B18,2)<>0)," < ","")`

I don't have the full dataset to test.. hope you verify and share if it works (or not).

( :

Comment: Thanks, however this only returns the thickness not the corresponding percentage in the table

Comment: can you share what exactly did you get in your A30 cell ? Does the " < " symbol shows ?

Comment: It came back with " < 10 "

Comment: is the value @ B8, E8, B18  is 19, MALE, and 9.2 ? in my case I get " < 0.41" || If I'm not mistaken.. in your current file.. the content of T5 is no longer the same as the screenshot you've shared.. may be the "0.41" value is now located at U5 instead.. is that the case?

Comment: If that's the case just change the `T5:X20` in the formula to `U5:Y20` will do.

Comment: Think I must have tried it on an old file, tried the formula again and it works! Thank you for your help, have been pulling my hair out over it!